# RecyclerView changes the height when scrolled how to solve this?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I'm using a recyclerview in order to show some photos of products, when I open the app it works amazing but when I scroll, the height of each card gets a lot bigger  and then when I open the keyboard the height gets it's best size and then when I scroll, it gets this bad size again, I can't figure out how to fix that.

xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
   android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:clipToPadding="false"
   android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Adapter

```
public  class ProductsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductsAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private Context mContext;
private List<Product> productList;

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.product_card, parent, false);

    return new ProductsAdapter.ViewHolder(itemView);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Product album = productList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(album.getName());
    holder.price.setText(album.getPrice() + " DZA");

    // loading album cover using Glide library
    Glide.with(mContext).load(album.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);

    holder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showPopupMenu(holder.overflow);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return productList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView title, price;
    public ImageView thumbnail, overflow;

    public ViewHolder (View itemView){
        super (itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.count);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        overflow = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.overflow);
    }
}

public ProductsAdapter(Context mContext, List<Product> productList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.productList = productList;
}
private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
    // inflate menu
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_product_card, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener());
    popup.show();
}
class MyMenuItemClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

    public MyMenuItemClickListener() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add_favourite:
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Add to favourite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_play_next:
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Play next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
        }
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

product_card.xml
       `

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardMaxElevation="8dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_album_radius">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/album_cover_height"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:textColor="@color/album_title"
                android:textSize="@dimen/album_title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/count"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/title"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/songs_count_padding_bottom"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:textSize="@dimen/songs_count" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/overflow"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_height"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_margin_top"
               android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_dots" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show you adapter code

Comment: can you comment  **Glide.with(mContext).load(album.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);** line and test. Just to make sure its not a problem with glide

Comment: and also it would be better if you `post product_card.xml `

Comment: I've just tried it ,always the same problem

Comment: @Raghunandan I've just posted the product_card.xml, did you find any mistake or something ..?

Comment: not sure but you can get rid of linerlayout.

Comment: and what do I use instead?

Comment: nothing. cardview is a viewgroup. This could be a problem with glide. i have added glide tag. But what happens if you just show text not image. comment out image related code in xml and adapter and check

Comment: I did all what you've asked @Raghunandan and always the same thing, So I guess it's not because of images

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed the problem, it was all about wrap_content and match_parent I made a very stupid mistake sorry everyone.
I changed match_parent to wrap_content in cardview and this works perfectly now.
Thanks guys.